# How to make a Hardware in loop experiment with OMNET++

Tags: raspberry-pi, omnet++

I want to use a simple hardware in loop experiment using OMNET++ So, I thought about using two raspberry pi's for example as nodes and try to connect them via the simulator, as a simple communication scenario.

any one have an idea about how can I do such a connection?

Comment: have got your problem worked out? I want to do the similay experiment as you. If you already have a sulotion, i need your help.